# iOS 10 Safari Issue with <select> element no more in DOM

Tags: safari, ios10

With this link you can reproduce the bug.

https://jsfiddle.net/pw7e2j3q/

```
<script>
$( "#test" ).change(function() {
  $("#test").remove();
  var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "test2").attr("name", "test");
  combo.append("<option>New One</option>");
  $("#App").append(combo);
});

$("#click").click(function(){
  $("#App").remove();
})
</script>
```

If you click on a `<select>` element and remove it from dom and after that you click on the link test. You should see the old `<select>` element pop for selection.

is there some hack to fix that ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the exact nature of problem. I am also facing the same problem in a datepicker. Wasn't sure what the exact problem was, not able to find a fix for the same as of yet. Will keep you updated incase I make some progress.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, nothing of note anywhere about  a fix

Comment: This is probably caused by the same iOS bug as http://stackoverflow.com/q/39557023/37168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue. The problem is, whenever you are trying to remove the select box on its change event then iOS10 is not able to properly unbind the selectbox. To fix this you need to put your code change event code inside a setTimeout with some timeout value. It is not working with zero timeout value.

http://jsfiddle.net/n62e07ef/

Below is a fix for your code:

```
<script>
$( "#test" ).change(function() {
  setTimeout( function() {
    $("#test").remove();
    var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", "test2").attr("name", "test");
    combo.append("<option>New One</option>");
    $("#App").append(combo);
  }, 50);
});

$("#click").click(function(){
  $("#App").remove();
})
</script>
```

Comment: it's weird no ?

Comment: Weird enough, but this bug can be due to the recent input type changes that Apple did in iOS10. Though there have been 2 minor releases after iOS10 release but they haven't fixed this problem as of yet. Looks like this problem is to stay for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be change the code a bit so don't re-generate the whole select-element, but just the option-elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon this bug today. It's like Gautam says in his answer that the event wont unbind before the element it removed.
My solution, [blur the element before removing it](http://codepen.io/Razzbrazz/pen/aBoNbE).

```
 $("#test").blur().remove();
```